# Why does unity gives me error about IEnumerator

Tags: c#

Hello i have problem with this, its a movement script that includes dash, and i when i run game i get this error **error CS0138: A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'IEnumerator' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead**
i am not sure why, if someone can help please.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.IEnumerator;
using static UnityEngine.Random;

public class Character2DController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MovementSpeed = 6;
    public float JumpForce = 8;
    public Animator animator;
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;
 
    //dash
    public float dashDistance = 15f;
    bool isDashing;
    float doubleTapTime;
    KeyCode lastKeyCode;
    

   private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

   
   private void Update()
    {
        

         
      var movement = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
      transform.position += new Vector3(movement,0,0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;

    animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(movement));


      if (!Mathf.Approximately(0, movement)){
      transform.rotation = movement > 0 ? Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0) : Quaternion.identity;
      }

      if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) < 0.011)
      {
          _rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

      }
     
    if (Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) > 0.000000001)
    {
        animator.SetFloat("jump", 2);
    }
  
    else if  (_rigidbody.velocity.y < 0.011){
        animator.SetFloat("jump", 1);}
    //dashing left
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)){
        if(doubleTapTime > Time.time && lastKeyCode == KeyCode.A){
            StartCoroutine(Dash(-1f));
        } else { doubleTapTime = Time.time + 0.5f; 
        }
       
        lastKeyCode = KeyCode.A;

    }
//dashing right
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)){
        if(doubleTapTime > Time.time && lastKeyCode == KeyCode.D){
            StartCoroutine(Dash(1f));
        } else { doubleTapTime = Time.time + 0.5f; 
        }
       
        lastKeyCode = KeyCode.D;

    }
 void FixedUpdate(){

     if(!isDashing) {
     _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * MovementSpeed, _rigidbody.velocity.y);
   }
}
    
    iEnumerator Dash (float direction){
        isDashing = true;
        _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(_rigidbody.velocity.x, 0f);
        _rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(dashDistance * direction, 0f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        float gravity = _rigidbody.gravityScale;
        _rigidbody.gravityScale = 0;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);
        isDashing = false;
        _rigidbody.gravityScale = gravity;


    }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: there i fixed it

Comment: The error explicitly tells you which using statement is the problem. Just remove the last part, so you refer to the namespace System.Collections and all should be good.

Comment: did u mean remove this using                                          
  System.Collections.IEnumerator;
using static UnityEngine.Random;

Comment: No, I mean remove the part of the statement that it is complaining about (The IEnumerator part).

Comment: oh u mean to remove just IEnumerator, but now i get this error ** error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'iEnumerator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: You have a lowercase i there.

Comment: oh, thanks its fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that IEnumerator is a type like List is type you do not write.

```
using System.Collections.Generic.List;
```

You would also not write

```
using System.Collections.List;
```

You would instead write

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Then you could use the list type in your code without writing out the entire thing.
IEnumerator is in the  "using System.Collections;" namespace. So you would add that to the top then use IEnumerator like you would use a List type.

Also when you change the namespace to.

```
using System.Collections;
```

I would also like to note you have a typo it is written iEnumerator should be IEnumerator.

Comment: Small correction: IEnumerator is in the System.Collections namespace. IEnumerator<T> is in the System.Collections.Generic namespace.

Comment: Yep, that is my bad I assumed he was using generic for some reason.